# В каком отношении можно употребить слово "изъять"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Верно ли будет такое предложение "Полицейские изъяли более килограмма синтетических наркотиков в жилище 22-летнего и 23-летнего местных жителей"? Получается, что наркотики изъяли в жилище". Мне кажется, что это слово лучше употреблять по отношению к человеку, то есть "изъять у кого-то". Или это всё же допустимо?

Answer (score 1):

Полицейские **изъяли** более килограмма синтетических наркотиков **в жилище/из жилища** двух местных жителей.

ИЗЪЯТЬ, св. что. Офиц. **Устранить** (из употребления, из обращения). И. из обращения старые денежные знаки. И. книгу из продажи. // **Удалить, вынуть**. И. осколок из раны. // **Отобрать, конфисковать**. При обыске было изъято много ценностей.

**Можно изъять что-то (у кого-то или из чего, где, откуда).**

**Примеры:**
 Кэри предлагает «изъять **из школ и колледжей** и даже вообще запретить» творчество Мильтона.  Что помимо трех миллионов долларов, о которых сообщалось ранее, было изъято **на дачах, в офисах и квартирах** задержанных?

Answer (score 0):

Имеется в виду, что событие (изъятие) произошло в жилище. Подразумевается, что наркотики были найдены именно в этом жилище и изъяты из обращения (то есть перешли в руки полиции). А фразу я бы перестроил, например, так:

**Полицейские изъяли более килограмма синтетических наркотиков в жилище двух местных жителей двадцати двух и двадцати трех лет.**